# How to make an up arrow disappear smoothly oce it touch the landing page's pic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

Please help guys !
I have an arrows that takes me to the landing page when I click on it. I want it to disappear smoothly once it touch landing page's pic. I want to do with CSS.

This is the source code:

```html
<!-- Start Bottom to scroll you up  -->

<div class="scrollUp">

  <a href="#header" id="button">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
  </a>


  <style>
      /* To style a button that helps to scroll up */
      @keyframes mymove{
          100%{transform: translate(0px, -10px);

          }
      }
      #button {
          position: fixed;
          right: 2%;
          bottom: 2%;
          height: 60px;
          width: 60px;
          color: #10cab7;
          font-size: 35px;
          animation: mymove 2s infinite;
          z-index: 1;
          background-color: #2d2c2d;
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 12px ;
          border-radius: 50%;
      }
      #button:hover{
          cursor: pointer;
          color: #38f8e5;
          transition: all 0.3s;
      }
  </style>
  
</div>
<!-- End Bottom to scroll you up  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use transition property of css for smooth movement.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

This link refers you to w3schools tutorial on transition property. Hope this link is helpful.

Comment: I actually want it to fade smoothly WHEN it touches the pic on landing page. What to use in this case ?

Comment: Yeah you you can use js like when clicked then set display none. The transition will take care of  fading smoothly

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Sorry i might explained it wrong. I have a landing pic that cover most of the page. Also I have an up-arrow that is not visible when I am scrolled at the landing pic because the pic z-index is more than the arrow's. 
Whether i click the arrow or not, I want it to disappear when i am scrolled on the pic. Also appear in the same manner again when I am scrolled down. Did you get my point
?

Comment: Then using js you can check like this. Img.addEventListener(’scroll',()=>{button.style.display='none'});.                                            The transition should already be present in the button CSS. And the reverse should be this codes opposite.